# Equal arrays but not the same visually

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras

[image]

I have a 32x32x3 image, say for example one of the cifar10 images in keras.
Now, say I want to do some manipulation. First, to make sure I am doing things right, I was trying to copy the image (that is not I want to do, so please don't tell me how to copy the image without doing three loops, I need the three loops to manipulate some values).

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
im = numpy.reshape(X_train[0], (3, 32, 32))
im = im.transpose(1,2,0)
imC = numpy.zeros((32,32,3))

for k in range(3):
  for row in range(0,32):
    for col in range(0,32):
      imC[row][col][k] = im[row][col][k]
```

Now, if I test if they are the same, they are, in fact I see "cool" printed out

```
if (im==imC).all():
  print "cool"
```

But when I try to visualize them, they are different:

```
plt.imshow( imC )
plt.show()

plt.imshow( im )
plt.show()
```

What is going on?

Comment: How are they different? Maybe you can add the plots to this question

Comment: What are the element types of the two arrays? (`im.dtype`, `imC.dtype`)

Comment: @Gareth, I think you are thinking in the right direction, I get (im.dtype, imC.dtype) = (uint8, float64)

Comment: I edited the title, maybe it may turn useful for someone else. If I modify the code to 'imC = numpy.zeros((32,32,3), numpy.uint8)' then it works. How can I make this question possibly useful for someone else making my same mistake (not setting the correct dtype)?

Comment: I think `imshow` expects RGB values in float m-by-n-by-3 arrays to be normalized to the range 0..1. What happens if you do `plt.imshow(imC/255)`?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It works as well. So, I am still perplexed though, because when I printed out the values for im they are from 0 to 255, and when I checked if the arrays were the same they did come out to be the same.

Comment: The point is that `imshow` explicitly looks at the element-type of the array you give it, and does different things for `uint8` and `float64`.

Comment: If you like to make it an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't know if it makes any sense, but the colors are just reversed on the two pictures. So as you already know that may be because imshow handles them differently.

Comment: OK, I made it an answer. (I hadn't done before because I still hadn't figured out why you get the particular results you do. But now I have. I think it's quite funny.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images in the Python CIFAR10 dataset have pixel values of type `numpy.uint8`. (Presumably they are read from PNG files or something of the kind.) So `X_train.dtype == numpy.uint8` and hence `im.dtype == numpy.uint8`.

The array you create has the default element type of `numpy.float64`. In other words, `imC.dtype == numpy.uint8`.

It happens that `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` treats its input differently depending on its element type. In particular, if you give it an *m*-by-*n*-by-3 array of element type `uint8` it will take 0 to mean darkest and 255 to mean lightest for each of the three colour channels, as you would expect; if you give it an *m*-by-*n*-by-3 array of element type `float64`, though, it wants all the values to be in the range 0 (darkest) to 1 (lightest), and the documentation says nothing about what will happen to values outside that range.

I will hazard a guess at what does happen to values outside that range: I think the code probably does something like: multiply by 255, round to integer, treat as `uint8`. This means at 0 becomes 0 and 1 becomes 255.

But if that last step means throwing away all but the low 8 bits, it also means that 2 becomes 254, 3 becomes 253, ..., 255 becomes 1! In other words, if you make the very understandable mistake of giving `imshow` an image whose pixel values are floats in the range 0..255, those values will effectively be negated so that 0->0, 1->255, 2->254,...,255->1. (This isn't quite the same as turning the range exactly upside down, because 0 is preserved.)

And this is what's happened to you: each element of `imC` is numerically equal to the corresponding element of `im`, but because `imC` is a float array rather than an unsigned-small-integer array it gets the treatment described above, and you get almost a photographic negative of the image you expected.

Comment: Best answer ever I got on a question!

Comment: Thanks. Glad to be of service!